# ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library 'lib_mysqludf_sys.so' (errno: 193 )

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysql-udf

I am using MySQL 5.6.11 running on 32-bit Microsoft Windows XP (Professional Version 2002 Service Pack 3). I am interested in installing the MySQL [`sys_exec`](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys) UDF.

The following command,

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'plugin_dir';
```

shows the following plugin location.

```
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                               |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| plugin_dir    | C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib\plugin\ |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

Where I pasted `lib_mysqludf_sys.so`. Then running the following command,

```
CREATE FUNCTION sys_exec RETURNS INT SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_sys.so';
```

from the MySQL command line results in the following error (after login has been made into the root user and an already created database has been selected).

> ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library 'lib_mysqludf_sys.so'
>   (errno: 193 )

How to fix this error?

<sub>Is `msvcp110.dll` needed under `C:\WINDOWS\system32`? It is not available there. The file `msvcp100.dll` is however, located under `C:\WINDOWS\system32`.</sub>

Comment: 'lib_mysqludf_sys.so' is a Linux shared library.  For Windows, you need it compiled as a Windows .dll.  ALSO: Msvcp110.dll or msvcp100.dll are two different files, for two different versions of Microsoft Visual C runtime (MSVC 10.0 and 11.0, respectively).  I don't know what they have to do with getting the MySQL UDF plugin working.

Comment: How can this be done? This is beyond me as not actively concerned with back-ends.

Comment: @Tiny the link you shared also includes the c source. You need to compile the c source to a dll (windows version of a linux .so file). Instructions to do that are here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/udf-compiling.html It has linux and windows instructions, windows is about 1/3 down the page

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a .dll file instead of creating .so file. .so file is used in Linux & .dll file is used in windows.

Check OS of your Mysql server by running below query.

show variables like 'version_compile_os'

create a dll file for same os version in windows.

To change the platform step in VS 2010 is as below.

Right click on project >> Click on Configuration Manager(Upper right side) >> Platform (if Mysql server is win32 then choose Win32 & if MySQL server is win64 then choose x64 Or win64 over here.)

Now create a dll file properly as do the same step as you mentioned. I hope it will work properly.

Comment: Vinieth, I am not sure for the file format for a mac, but you can find out by performing below steps.

1. All plugins are installed in plugin directory. To find out plugin directory, run below command.
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'plugin_dir'

2. Check file format of files in this directory. This will be a file format for mac.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `make.exe` you are running using `cygwin` or `32 bit`. If you are using Netbeans I suggest to check your Tool Collection Settings (Tools->Options). See if you are using `mingw32-make.exe` for make command.

Compiling on `MYSQL` is somewhat painful as there are many moving parameters between versions and operating systems. if you like to walk thru all compilation process from scratch the following repository is a good place to look at

https://github.com/esabilbulbul/mysql-udf-windows